# GKE MasterAuth clientCertificate has no permissions to access cluster resource

Tags: google-api, google-kubernetes-engine

I created GKE cluster using GKE API. Below is the payload and end point I used.

*API:* https://container.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*/locations/*}/clusters

*Method:* POST

*RequestBody:*

{
  "cluster": {
    "name": "test",
    "masterAuth": {
      "clientCertificateConfig": {
        "issueClientCertificate": true
      }
    }....
   }
......
.....
}

*NOTE:* I'am creating GKE cluster with masterAuth enabled by setting clientCertificate to true. After cluster creation, I created the kubeconfig in my local machine  using the clusterCaCertificate, clientCertificate and clientKey information from the GKE API ie., by describing the cluster.

- Then I listed the nodes using 'kubectl get nodes' command and the response was

> Error from server (Forbidden): nodes is forbidden: User "client"
>   cannot list resource "nodes" in API group "" at the cluster scope

The clusterCaCertificate information provided by the GKE describe APIs has the ***CN="client"***  but it should have been "***admin***". clusterCaCertificate is generated by Google and as a developer I could not find a way of setting the CN. I cannot even access the cluster so cannot perform any roleBinding or similar for user '***client***'.   Any idea how this can be resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here for a  [workaround](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/278#issuecomment-439627987) and how GKE Engineering team is working on [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/111101728). I took this from the GitHub report:

> So per recommendation, I did post on the [kubernetes engine bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187077&template=0) and it became this private issue:
>
> https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/111101728, feel free to reference it, which is equivalent to [kubernetes/kubernetes#65400](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/65400).
>
> In a nutshell, the client cert has CN=client encoded and client user doesn't have any permissions. If you use masterAuth username/password (basic auth), then you can apply the yaml.
>
> ```
> kind: ClusterRoleBinding
> apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
> metadata:
>   name: client-binding
> subjects:
> - kind: User
>   name: client
> roleRef:
>   kind: ClusterRole
>   name: "cluster-admin"
>   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
> ```
>
> Which will give the user on the cert admin permissions. Additionally, to remove basic auth you can set the username="" in the api, but this will cause a reboot which will take 5 more minutes to do a master switch.

Comment: You can use masterAuth / basic auth from the GKE web interface to apply the above binding: `kubectl apply binding.yaml --username=admin --password=XXX`